# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in openCV while trying to detect nameplates of cars

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to working on image processing. I have a folder that has images of various cars. I am trying to extract only their nameplates and put it in a different folder. I am getting an error stating "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" in line 5 of the below code. I looked up for this code on the internet and trying to understand it. As far as I could figure out, we are first using the **imread** function to read the image and converting it into gray color space. The Canny function helps detect edges and findContours helps find the contours of the image. I don't seem to understand the code further ahead. It will be helpful if someone could guide me through the code as well as help me sort the error.

```
import cv2 
image = cv2.imread("path")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[4]
cv2.drawContours(im2, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
idx = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w>50 and h>50:
        idx+=1
        new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
cv2.imshow("im",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: @chitown88 thanks for the reply. it was just some editing problem. fixed it

Comment: @chitown88, seems to work fine for me

Comment: I guess you're using OpenCV 3.x, and reading documentation or tutorial written for 2.x -- the API changed and `findContours` in 3.x returns 3 values instead of two. Another sign is that you give it a copy of the input image (in 2.x it modified the input).

Comment: looking into it, it seems to have changed with cv 3.0. I think I found it, so testing now and will post back to you

Comment: @DanMašek Yes thank you so much. I got it.

Comment: @chitown88 , thanks but unable to get the nameplate of the car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change in cv 3.0
Has to do with `.findContours` returns 3 values now.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

```
import cv2 
image = cv2.imread("path")
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 10, 250)

#old way
#(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# 3.0 way
_, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

idx = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w>50 and h>50:
        idx+=1
        new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
cv2.imshow("im",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, But i am unable to detect the nameplate.

Answer (score 0):

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```